# page slide for exposing left menu with twitter bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to emulate or find a plugin that slides the page over exposing a navigation menu like this [twitter bootstrap template](http://nightskyadmin.com/demo/template/dashboard.html):

If you resize the page you'll see the option in the header row to slide the page over.

I've looked through the javascript code but don't see how this is accomplished.

I also found this git project for [pageslide](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/) but it slides the entire page.

Any idea how this bootstrap page slides the menu out for smaller resolution devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically page structure and some css3 transforms/styles.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="menu" role="navigation"></div>
    <div id="main" role="main"></div>
</div>
```

The page uses media queries to set styles based on available screen real-estate and applying the style js-menu to the html element:

When open (abbreviated):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 950px)
    .js-advanced.js-menu #wrap {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(280px, 0, 0);
    }
```

When closed (abbreviated):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 950px)
    .js-advanced #wrap {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
```

In this case, the entire #wrap element is being shifted over.

I've created a gist for a very [simple/stripped down version](https://gist.github.com/davidcl64/6073258) of a page that has basic support for both newer and some older browsers.  I did not add media query support.  Media query support can be added for older browser via libraries like [respondjs](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond).

Comment: @dcp thanks for the info...starting to make a little more sense now

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good solution for older browsers...am I correct?

Comment: Correct - to support older browsers you would need use a class that  manipulates left/right/etc rather than using transform and, if the animation was important to you for those browsers, either use a library or implement that yourself.  You may also need to detect changes to your available width/height depending on how far back you go... or just call it good enough.

Comment: @Paul - added a link for [quick, stripped down sample](https://gist.github.com/davidcl64/6073258)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using then panel widget from the latest jquerymobile (1.3.0). Maybe this is not what you want but there are options so you could do it programatically. http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/panels/panel-fixed.html